# Core Data Image with Custom TableViewCell in Swift

Tags: swift, image, core-data, tableview, option-type

I am new to Swift and iOS Development, and have not found a specific answer to my question.

I am attempting to populate a custom tableview with 3 Labels and 2 Images using Core Data.

I read up on optionals and have even built something similar to what I am trying to do now using the Subtitle option when creating the cell in the storyboard. That works.

My Core Data set up looks like this at the top of the class:

```
// MARK: - Managed Object Context

var moc = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

// Initialize Fetch Results

var fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController()

func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest {

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Custom")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "customFourImages", ascending: true)

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    return fetchRequest
}

// MARK: - Retrieve Request

func getFetchRequest() -> NSFetchedResultsController {

    fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: moc!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    return fetchedResultsController
}
```

My viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear look like this:

```
// MARK: - Fetch

    fetchedResultsController = getFetchRequest()
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

    do {
        try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
    } catch {
        print("Failed to Perform Initial Fetch")
        return
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Finally, my cellForRowAtIndexPath looks like this:

```
 // MARK: - Dequeue Reusable Cell

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

    // MARK: - Initiate Fetch Results for Index Path

    let custom = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Custom

    let customLabel = custom.customLabels
    let customTwoLabel = custom.customTwoLabels
    let customThreeLabel = custom.customThreeLabels

    let image = UIImage(named: "Custom Food")
    let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!)
    custom.customFourImages = imageData

    let images = UIImage(named: "Custom Drink")
    let imagesData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(images!)
    custom.customFiveImages = imagesData

    // MARK: - Set Items in Cell to Returned Fetched Results

    cell.customLabel?.text = "\(customLabel)"
    cell.customTwoLabel?.text = "\(customTwoLabel)"
    cell.customThreeLabel?.text = "\(customThreeLabel)"
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: custom.customFourImages!)
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: custom.customFiveImages!)

    return cell
}
```

I have tried every permutation that I can think of and have scoured the Internet and StackOverflow for a specific answer. I would also prefer not to use Strings. I am using imagePickerController. But even with images in my imageAssets, e.g. "Custom Food", "Custom Drink", image is still found nil.

I can't crack it!

Comment: Hi, where exactly is your code failing? How are your saving your images to core data? and could you please update your code to show what the Custom class entails? Images would need to be saved as NSData, and you should unwrap your optionals before using them.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for replying: The code fails at unwrapping the images. They are found nil. Swift is telling me to unwrap them e.g. cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: custom.customFourImages!)

Comment: But it crashes every time. I have a CustomTableViewCell where customLabel, customTwoLabel, etc. have IBOutlets and everything is connected in the storyboard.

Comment: I am using a TabBarController and every time I click on the Custom tabBar icon it crashes and the report is "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping" (lldb).

Comment: Here is how I am saving Images in another viewController called "WorkViewController"
        
        do {
            try moc?.save()
        } catch {
            print("New Photo Failed")
            return
        }
    }

Answer (score 1):

From your comments I can't workout where you are actually saving your managed objects to Core Data. you mention that you use *try.moc?.save()* but are you saving your individual images to core data? Furthermore, if your images are stored locally in the device, and not fetched from an URL, then you don't really need core data for this.

In the case that you are fetching your images from a URL or whatever, and assuming that you have added an entity *MyImage* with a *imageData* property of type NSData, you need to save the object like so:

```
class func createInManagedObjectContext(moc: NSManagedObjectContext, imgData: NSData) ->MyImage {
    let newItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("MyImage", inManagedObjectContext: moc) as! MyImage
    newItem.imageData = imagData
    return newItem
}
```

Add that function to your MyImage.Swift file (generated by Core Data), so that when you need to save a new image to core data you just do:

```
func saveNewImage(data: {DATA}){
    MyImage.createInManagedObjectContext(self.managedObjectContext, imgData: data);
}
```

Then, to fetch your objects:

```
func getSavedImages() -> [MyImage]? {
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    do {
        return try self.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as? [MyImage]
    } catch {
        print("no records found")
        return nil
    }
}
```

If you are already doing this, can you please update your code with more details? pointing out where your error is happening (line number).

If your Image is failing here:

```
cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: custom.customFourImages!)
cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: custom.customFiveImages!)
```

Your fetch result is not getting records from Core Data, which is probably an issue with the above.

if your code is failing here:

```
let images = UIImage(named: "Custom Drink")
let imagesData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(images!)
```

You should be unwraping your images object with an if let img = images { ... } and most likely the error would be related to the name of the UIImage that you are getting from memory.

I hope this helps.

Cheers.

**EDIT 1:**
In reply to your comments: 
try.moc.save will not save your images, it will persist any changes pending in the data model.

You need to actually create the managed object in core data, and you need to make sure that your fetch request is getting the relevant data out of Core Data.

Your code is failing because customFourImages is nil. Which in term comes from:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "Custom Food")
let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!)
custom.customFourImages = imageData

....

let images = UIImage(named: "Custom Drink")
let imagesData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(images!)
custom.customFiveImages = imagesData

...

cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: custom.customFourImages!)
cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: custom.customFiveImages!)
```

This all seems a bit redundant.

Try this:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "Custom Food")
let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!)
cell.imageView?.image = image
custom.createInManagedObjectContext(moc, imgData: imageData)
....

let images = UIImage(named: "Custom Drink")
let imagesData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(images!)
cell.imageView?.image = images //this is called in the same block? you are overwriting your imageView in the cell, maybe you have two?
custom.createInManagedObjectContext(moc, imgData: imagesData)
```

This will save the images to Core data and assign the right image to your cell view (I'm unsure if this will address your needs of saving images data to core data). Make sure you understand why you need to use core data and save the appropriate managed object that suits your requirements.

Comment: Thanks! I added the new functions to my Custom.swift file created by Core Data. The table is loading and I can post from my second view controller using UITextFields the values of customLabel, customLabelTwo, customLabelThree. But I still cannot fetch images. Reminder: I am using imagePickerController.

Comment: Yes. Images are stored locally on the device and also have camera functionality. And yes, I allowed for external storage, which I think is what you mean, in that I can use the NSFileManager.

Comment: If all your images are stored locally, why do you need Core Data storing your images?

Comment: Code is failing here: 'cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: custom.customFourImages!)' So I removed it to get the tableView to load. The labels are fetched from previous attempts to post images and labels, but no images. I am attempting to save images retrieved or taken from device to CoreData using _try.moc.save()_. Now I understand that there are no images "in CoreData" to retrieve. But I can pick them, replace the placeholder photo I have in UIImageView, and "post", except nothing appears.

Comment: Because I am using CoreData for everything else. I was aiming for continuity since I am new. Should I use NSFileManager or CloudKit instead?

Comment: **fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)** Yes, I have two imageViews, one for a profile and one for the content image. I think I am going to create a new NSManaged Subclass and look at NSFileManager, although I prefer to see this through. But I can't get it to work. Thank you for all your help, man!

Comment: It looks like let image = UIImage(named: "Custom Food") is returning nil, which will mean that "Custom Food" is not in your project or not part of the target. That's the only optional that you are unwrapping.

Comment: Okay, so that part I got working. "Custom Food" image is displaying but, as expected, in every single cell. Recall, I am trying to use imagePickerController in the app. When I go to add a new photo from my library it doesn't display. How can I choose an image from my device if I programmed the app to populate the tableview with essentially an array of my hard-coded UIImage(named: "Custom Food") image?

Comment: Solve it: My NSData object in my @NSManagedObject that Xcode creates in Subclass was set to optional. Removed optional value and everything works. Thanks, again!